# Quando acerto a palavra, ainda aparece um input no final

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo de adivinhação em Python, mas quando acerto a palavra no final ainda continua aparecendo um `input`.

CODIGO:

```
import random
Países("Países","alemanha","portugal","brasil","frança","russia","espanha","belgica","uk")
Alimentos=("Alimentos","pao","agua","batata","açucar","alface","arroz","tomate","bife","frango")
Clubes_Desportivos=("Clubes_Desportivos","fcp","slb","scp","manchester")
temas=[Países, Alimentos,Clubes_Desportivos]

tema= random.choice (temas)

palavra_secreta=random.choice(tema[1:])

letras_certas=[]

erros=0

LETRAS=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

dinheiro=500

tentativas=0

#Funções----------------------------

def mostra_palavra():
    global palavra_a_mostrar
    palavra_a_mostrar=""
    for i in palavra_secreta:
        if i in letras_certas:
            palavra_a_mostrar+=i
        else:
            palavra_a_mostrar+="_ " 
    print("A sua palavra é ", palavra_a_mostrar)
    print ("Erros: ", erros, "\nDinheiro ", dinheiro  )

#-----------------------------------

def avalia_palavra():
    global resposta, dinheiro, erros

    if resposta in palavra_secreta:
        dinheiro+=100
        letras_certas.append(resposta)
        mostra_palavra()
        resposta=input("Acertou numa letra. Escolha outra.")
    else:
        dinheiro-=200
        erros+=1
        mostra_palavra()
        resposta=input("Falhou. Escolha denovo ")



#----------------------------------    

#INICIO----------------------------

print("Seja bem vindo ao jogo de Advinhar palavras , pedimos-te  que indiques uma letra.\n Se acertares vais ganhar dinheiro. Tens 9 Possibilidades de errar ")
print("\n O seu tema é", tema[0])  

#Programa---------------------------

mostra_palavra()
resposta=input("Indique uma letra minuscula ") 


while erros <8 and "_" in palavra_a_mostrar:
    avalia_palavra()

#FIM------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está relacionado com a forma como você montou o laço `while`:

```
# Programa---------------------------
while True:

    mostra_palavra()

    if erros > 7 or "_" not in palavra_a_mostrar:
        break

    resposta = input("Indique uma letra minúscula ")
    avalia_palavra()
```

Neste caso a condição de saída do laço é justamente o oposto daquela que foi definida para manter a execução dentro dele.

Desta forma torna-se desnecessário chamar as funções `mostra_palavra()` e a `input()` de dentro da função `avalia_palavra()`:

```
def avalia_palavra():
    global dinheiro, erros

    if resposta in palavra_secreta:
        dinheiro += 100
        letras_certas.append(resposta)
    else:
        dinheiro -= 200
        erros += 1
```

E antes de terminar, duas coisinhas:

- Apesar de ser suportado em **Python** o uso de acentuação no nome das variáveis (`Países`), não é algo lá muito recomendável e
- Com relação ao uso de variáveis globais, o [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id44) (a famosa PEP8) recomenda o uso de variáveis globais somente dentro de módulos e o [Google Python Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Global_variables) Guide sugere que não se deve usar. Neste caso você pode fazer o mesmo definindo uma classe ou simplesmente passando e recebendo estes valores através das funções.